# Modify the AD8232 chip configuration to use only LEFT and RIGHT arm in steel leads configuration

Tags: biopotential, ecg

I am an industrial designer (little experience with electronics) trying to modify one of the [AD8232](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8232.html) chip configurations. The AD8232 is a Single-Lead, Heart Rate Monitor Front End. In the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8232.pdf), page 24 there is an exercise to measure heart rate signal at your hands with steel electrodes. This is the one (see image below) I would like to modify to get a good signal from steel electrodes, but without the right leg electrode.

[image]

I am working on a breadboard using a breakout for the AD8232. So far I do not get good results, I tried to use a configuration like can be seen below.

[image]

I need help with the configuration and setup, perhaps there are better ways to achieve the end result, I am open to ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Without a knowledge on CMRR using active guarding using RLdrive feedback or RLDFB contact, how can we explain why this is important?

Comment: first thing first ..... do you get good results if you use the leg electrode?

Comment: Quote from the datasheet: `The RLD circuit drives to the third electrode, which can also be
located at the hands, to cancel common-mode interference.`

Comment: @jsotola yes I get good results using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want connections from RLD to BOTH arm electrodes.  I suggest trying to connect to only ONE of the arm electrodes, through \$360k\Omega \$, and not \$10M\Omega\$.  You *want* to use one of the arm electrodes as the reference, and you don't want to separate it with large impedance.

Comment: Although I still don't understand very well the principle behind our recommendation, it works better as you suggested. Moreover, I would like to know a bit more. What do you mean by You want to use one of the arm electrodes as the reference, and you don't want to separate it with large impedance? - What do you mean by separate?